# When to store quaternion vs matrix in static and dynamic objects (data structure design)

Tags: matrix, 3d, game-engine, quaternions

My question is about design and possible suggestions for the following scenario:

I am writing a 3d visualizer.  For my renderable objects I would like to store the minimum data possible (so quaternions are naturally nice for rotation).

At some point I must extract a Matrix for rendering which requires computation and temporary storage on every frame update (even for objects that do not change spatially).

Given that many objects remain static and don't need to be rotated locally would it make sense to store the matrix instead and thereby avoid the computation for each object each frame?  Is there any best practice approach to this perhaps from a game engine design point of view?

I am currently a bit torn between storing the two extremes of either position+quaternion or 4x3/4x4 matrix. Looking at openframeworks (not necessarily trying to achieve the same goal as me), they seem to do a hybrid where they store a quaternion AND a matrix (matrix always reflects the quaternion) so its always ready when needed but needs to be updated along with every change to the quaternion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been there.

First: keep in mind the omnipresent struggle of time against space (in computer science processing time against memory requirements)

You said that want to keep minimum information possible at first (space), and next talked about some temporary matrix reflecting the quartenions, which is more of a time worry.

If you accept a tip, I would go for the matrices. They are generally performance wise standard for 3D graphics and it's size becomes easily irrelevant next to the object data itself.

Just to have and idea: in most GPUs transforming an vector for the identity (no change) is actually faster then checking if it needs transformation and then doing nothing.

As for engines, I can't think of one that does not apply the transformations for every vertex every frame. Even if the objects keep in place, they position has to go through projection and view matrices.

(does this answer? Maybe I got you wrong)

Comment: Yes I'm inclined to agree with you. I am really trying to find a balance between space and time performance.  I think your reasoning makes sense, in that the space will be dwarfed by actual model data (though technically for models I could throw away the main memory representation of the model once its on the gpu right?)

So then the only reason for using quaternions would be as an intermediary when rotating (for quality and performance) rather than in the actual in memory model of an object.

Comment: So you are updating stuff to some GPU, and are concerned to general performance. This give room to some more precise answer. Yes, you can delete the cpu memory data after the update, and yes, quartenions will be intermediary representation in all its beauty and glory. At least that's initial recommendation. GPUs are so fast with 4x4 matrices (built in functions, parallel processing etc) that it's a natural choice. Even 2D drawing uses them with the remaining dimensions to default value. That's because they can represent about any linear transformation to 3D vectors that you can think of.

Comment: But, of course, the GPU pipeline is now entirely programmable, you can update the quartenions if you like (or anything, like a texture representing animation angles through time) and work there, or the equivalent matrix. Since CPU is much better with generic computations and branching, I recommend updating the final stuff in some standard format for everything.

Answer (score 2):

1. More compact storage require 3 scalars, so Euler Angels or Exponential Maps (Rodrigues) can be used. Quaternions is good compromise between conversion to matrix speed and compactness.
2. From design point of view , there is a good rule "make all design decisions as LATE as possible". In your case, just incapsulate (isolate) the rotation (transformation) representation, to be able in the future, to change the physical storage of data in different states (file, memory, rendering and more). Also it enables different platform optimization, keep data in GPU or CPU and more.